# Unable to detect if two rectangles are colliding C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a procedural room generator in c#, I would like the rooms not to overlap and I am having a hard time getting that to work. After @Idle_Mind's comments, I have a new problem. The Image produced by the program has many overlapping rooms. Bellow is the class that should handle the intersection checking and the placement of the rooms onto the tilemap

```
        public int XSize, YSize;
        private Cell[ , ] cells;
        private List<Room> rooms;

        public Tilemap(int xSize, int ySize)
        {
            XSize = xSize;
            YSize = ySize;
            rooms = new List<Room>();
            cells = new Cell[XSize, YSize];

            for (int y = 0; y < YSize; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < XSize; x++)
                {
                    cells[x, y].type = CellType.Empty;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                GenerateRandomRoomSafe(10);
            }
        }

        private Room GetRoomBounds()
        {

            Utils.Int2 min = new Utils.Int2(0, 0);
            Utils.Int2 max = new Utils.Int2(XSize,YSize);
            Utils.Int2 q1 = Utils.GetRandomCoords(min, max);

            max.X = XSize - 1 - q1.X;
            max.Y = YSize - 1 - q1.Y;

            Utils.Int2 siz = Utils.GetRandomCoords(min, max);
            Room check = new Room(q1.X, q1.Y, siz.X, siz.Y);


            return check;
        }

        public void GenerateRandomRoomSafe(int maxTries)
        {
            Room check = new Room(0, 0, 0, 0);
            bool isValid = false;
            int tries = 0;

            if (rooms.Count == 0)
            {
                isValid = true;
                check = GetRoomBounds();
                tries = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                while (!isValid && tries < maxTries)
                {
                    check = GetRoomBounds();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!rooms[i].Walls.IntersectsWith(check.Walls))
                        {
                            isValid = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    tries++;
                }
            }

            if (isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(check + " was placed after " + tries + " tries");
                PlaceRoomUnsafe(check);
            }
        }

        public void PlaceRoomUnsafe(Room r)
        {
            for (int y = r.Walls.Y; y <= r.Walls.Y + r.Walls.Height; y++)
            {
                cells[r.Walls.X, y].type = CellType.Wall;
            }
            for (int y = r.Walls.Y; y <= r.Walls.Y + r.Walls.Height; y++)
            {
                cells[r.Walls.X + r.Walls.Width, y].type = CellType.Wall;
            }
            for (int x = r.Walls.X; x <= r.Walls.X + r.Walls.Width; x++)
            {
                cells[x, r.Walls.Y].type = CellType.Wall;
            }
            for (int x = r.Walls.X; x <= r.Walls.X + r.Walls.Width; x++)
            {
                cells[x, r.Walls.Y + r.Walls.Height].type = CellType.Wall;
            }

            for (int y = r.Floor.Y; y < r.Floor.Y + r.Floor.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = r.Floor.X; x < r.Floor.X + r.Floor.Width; x++)
                {
                    cells[x, y].type = CellType.Floor;
                }
            }
            rooms.Add(r);
        }

        public void GenerateRandomRoomUnsafe()
        {
            Room r = GetRoomBounds();
            PlaceRoomUnsafe(r);
        }


        public int GetCellPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            return (int) cells[x, y].type;
        }


        public class Room
        {
            public Rectangle Walls;
            public Rectangle Floor;

            public Room(int q1X, int q1Y, int xSize, int ySize)
            {
                Walls.X = q1X;
                Walls.Y = q1Y;
                Walls.Width = xSize;
                Walls.Height = ySize;
                Floor.X = q1X + 1;
                Floor.Y = q1Y + 1;
                Floor.Width = xSize - 1;
                Floor.Height = ySize - 1;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "[Walls: " + Walls + "\n Floor: " + Floor + "]";
            }
        }
    }
```

Image below for reference[image]

Comment: I think the problem lies in one part of the referenced post, he assumes that the Y coordinate increases *from bottom to top*, when in screen coordinates this is just the opposite as Y increases from top to bottom.

Comment: You don't have to re-invent the wheel.  Use [Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle) and [Rectangle.IntersectsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith)?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I re-wrote the code, now the intersection appears not to work, with many rooms overlapping. The code on github is updated.

Comment: Github link not working. Update the code here, anyways...

Comment: Looks like you are only looking at X, Y coordinates.  Don't you need to include width and height?  Your code is needlessly complicated by not using the Rectangle class.

Comment: @Idle_Mind when someone tries to learn how to invent the wheel there is no way around it.. :) though I upvoted your comment

Comment: Rewrote the code to use Rectangle, gives a different problem where the image produced has many intersections.

Comment: Your code won't compile unless your initialize your rectangle variables.  Anyway, like previously mentioned, if you have rectangles, now you can use the IntersectsWith function.

Comment: If you're having trouble solving a problem, solve a simpler problem. **Can you solve the problem "do any of these line segments overlap"**?  If you cannot solve the simpler problem, you cannot solve the harder problem. If you can solve the simpler problem, you can use that in your solution to the harder problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in `GenerateRandomRoomSafe()` is backwards.

In this code block:

```
while (!isValid && tries < maxTries)
{
    check = GetRoomBounds();
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!rooms[i].Walls.IntersectsWith(check.Walls))
        {
            isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    tries++;
}
```

What you're saying is, "If it doesn't intersect with at least one room, then it must be valid".

Just because it doesn't intersect with the current room, doesn't mean it won't intersect with a different one!

It should look more like: (note the comments)

```
while (!isValid && tries < maxTries)
{
    isValid = true; // assume it's good until proven otherwise
    check = GetRoomBounds();
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rooms[i].Walls.IntersectsWith(check.Walls)) // if it DOES intersect...
        {
            isValid = false; // .. then set valid to false.
            break;
        }
    }
    tries++;
}
```

So we start by assuming it is valid, then when we encounter a room that DOES intersect, we set valid to false and stop the `for` loop so another random room can be tried (assuming we haven't exceeded the number of tries).

Some of the maps it produced:

[image]